# How the Eclipse implements importing project?

Tags: eclipse, import

How the Eclipse implements importing project and which part of the Eclipse's codes works?
OK, we all know EC has function:file->import ->exsit project ...I am looking into the code of EC, but i cant find which part of it is used to implement this loading work.

Comment: You need to provide more details and a clearer question. It doesn't make much sense at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In the part of Eclipse that you want learn more about (in this case for example in the *Import Projects Wizard*), you can open the *Plug-in Spy* using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. It will tell you the class and the plug-in contributing the functionality. You can then check out the plug-in from the [Eclipse CVS](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/).